# Can I use a single SSL with multiple subdomains that all points to the same server?

Tags: tls

Our *staging* server has 1 domain pointing to it, and each of our customers apps are accessed with subdomains using virtual hosts (`CNAME` record has wildcard `*` on subdomains to point to the server as well).

Apple has forced developers to use SSL so we find ourselves unable to test certain functions on *staging environment* (or we have to dig 2 hours on a workaround), so I think it's more efficient if we just SSL it.

**Godaddy** seems to provide 3 tiers of SSL, the most expensive one says *secure one website and all it's subdomains* but I don't know if maybe that's for subdomains that points to different servers, so it is overkill for me. Any type of guidance will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks like a question for Godaddy. I think what you are looking for is info on "wildcard domain certs".

Answer (score 1):

You can use a certificate for all names contained in the certificate. It does not matter which IP address gets used in the end, if there are CNAMEs involved etc. The only thing which matters is if the hostname in the URL matches successfully against the certificate returned by the server, that means exact match or wildcard match against the names in the certificate.

It might be that you certificate provider has some more usage restrictions in the contract, but these are not technically enforced by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Logistically it is possible to have a single server use a wildcard certificate for many subdomains. The issue that you may run into is if you ever decide to have one of the subdomains on a different server. You would then either need to share the private keys across multiple servers or issue another certificate for the new server.

As Schroeder stated, this is a much better question for GoDaddy support as they will be best able to help you.